# How to add the git source code into a bb file

Tags: github, bitbake

This is the first time for me write the bb file, so please give me some help.

I can fetch the http tarball from external network, after I put it into the local source mirror directory, disable the external network and run the bb file, it works well. But when I tried to fetch a git source tarball, and do everything as before, the bb file failed to fetch the git source tarball from the source mirror after I disable the external network.

> ERROR: Task 587 (/$PATH/******.bb, do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
>   NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 402 tasks of which 382 didn't need to
>   be rerun and 1 failed.

The following is my bb file:

```
SRCBRANCH = "********"
SRCREV = "AUTOINC"

SRC_URI = "git://***************.git;branch=${SRCBRANCH};protocol=https"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;beginline=4;endline=16;md5=**********"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "***************"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "***************"


S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that as you use AUTOINC, the cause of your error can be checksum mismatch, but as you haven't provided error message from your do_fetch log, I cannot say for sure. You can find it by the path

build/tmp/work/*one_of_directories*/*name_of_your_recipe*/*version*/tmp/log.do_fetch